# Extraction of single point layer out multiple points (having same lat lon) using Line feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, select-by-attribute

I am having point feature with same latitude and longitude so placed one over other in multiple places. like figure one:
I have line feature which having stormID which is same as storm id in point.
so Based upon this common id among point and line I would like to extract same storm id's point from point.

I can't use select by field value as same storm id has multiple points and by default it is taking first point ( which proofs wrong for my analysis).

[image: Figure one: Selected point has two points so need to select only one with storm id AL041917 which same as line feature]

All of these points located end of line either start or end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using a `virtual layer`.

Go the the menu `layer / add layer / add-edit virtual layer` and enter the following query. You would have to change the layer name and field name(s) to suit your needs.

The output is a dynamic layer, which you can then export (Shapefile or else).

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM points p
  JOIN lineLyaer l ON ST_INTERSECTS(l.geometry,p.geometry)
   AND l.stormID = p.stormI
```

The new layer will contain all points that are both connected to a line and that have the same stormID as the line.